# Como obtengo el id de un documento en especial en firestore para luego pasarlo a un componente y poder usar su informacion

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, firestore

Quiero traerme el id del documento(2WKUL....) y no puedo
Aca lo que estoy haciendo es ingresar a la aplicacion con firestore
esto es firebase-config, me traigo firestore
[y en homescreen quiero traerme ese id del documento para poder mostrar los datos en ese componente y no me sale
[image: Quiero traerme el id del documento(2WKUL....) y no puedo]

[image: Aca lo que estoy haciendo es ingresar a la aplicacion con firestore]

[image: esto es firebase-config, me traigo firestore]
[image: y en homescreen quiero traerme ese id del documento para poder mostrar los datos en ese componente y no me sale]

Comment: Hola Francisco, bienvenido, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias.